# How to fix the position of divs in a parent div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create div that contains scrollable content.  To do this I created a parent div that hides overflow content and I have two divs that allow users to scroll through the child content.  The problem is that my two divs that allow users to scroll are moving when they are clicked.  I would like their position to stay fixed within the parent div.

If that does not make sense please take a look at the jsFiddle below.  When you click the text that says "Down!" you will see everything on the page (including the "Down!" text) move down.  I would like "Down!" to stay where it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ecA7/

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="up">UP!</div>
    <div id="down">DOWN!</div>
    <div id="content">
        Scrolling content       
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#container
{
 height:200px;
 width:400px;   
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#up
{
    position:absolute;
    top:3px;
    left:3px;
}
#down
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:3px;
    left:3px;
}
#content
{
 left:80px;   
 position:relative;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#up").click(function () {
            $("#container").animate({ scrollTop: $("#container").position().top - 40 }, 500);
            //$("#container").position().top - 40.scrollTop();
        });

        $("#down").click(function () {
            $("#container").animate({ scrollTop: $("#container").position().top + 40 }, 500);
        });
   });
```

Comment: Can't you put the 'down' div outside the container div? Then it stays fixed.

Comment: I might be able to do that.  The problem is that the parent div can be of varying height and I need "Down!" to always be at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've constructed a simple [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/Aj7xT/) to show my (new) way. I think I succeeded rather well.

The point is to have 2 divs outside the scrolling content, which are in this case `position: absolute;` for the sake of looks alone. which control the content but not scroll with it.

Comment: +1, this looks very promising.  I'm going to make some tweaks and I'll report back.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4ecA7/1/

Remove them from inside that div. Absolute positioning gives you the ability to position your elements:

```
/*CSS Change*/
#down
{
    position:absolute;
    top:185px;
    left:3px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I might be able to do that.  Would this still work if the height of #container can vary?

Comment: You are forced to set a height on `#container` to make it scroll, as long as you position the DOWN link appropriately in relation to that, it should be fine.

Comment: It would probably work better to have both #up and #down set to a relative position, and not absolute, if you remove them from the container.

Comment: @Karl, I set the height for the purpose of the example.  Unfortunately when it's released into the wild, users can configure how high this element is.

Comment: You can dynamically reposition the elements with jQuery if this is the case, the idea is the same it'd just be relative the current height of the box rather than being precalculated.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to dynamically reposition the elements with jQuery?  I've tried a few things but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your container has its `position` value set to `relative`.  That makes all inner element's with an `absolute` position, absolute in relation to the container, not the page.  So when the container scrolls, the inner divs scroll.  Either remove them from the container, or remove `position:relative` from the container div.